# Not getting value after whitespace while passing variable from android to php

Tags: php, android

I am trying to pass a variable from android to php, while receiving value in php does not get values after whitespace. I am passing variable like,

```
private void register(String txtname) {
String urlSuffix = "?name="+txtname;
 Log.d("unmae",txtname);
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(UserRegister.this,"Please Wait","Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
           loading.dismiss();
                      }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
                HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                bufferReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
                result = bufferReader.readLine();
                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                return null;
            }
        }
    }

        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
        ru.execute(urlSuffix);
}
```

**On Php side**

```
$uname = $_GET['name'];
```

While log the variable, the output is like this
Eg: `unmae:first second`

whie the echo in php side it appears like this

Eg: `$uname = $_GET['name'];`
 `echo $uname;`
 `output:first`

Comment: this happens because in the parameter you can't have a space i think, try to replace the space with a symbol and then in php find that symbol and make it a space

Comment: replace it with "%20"

Comment: It is unclear if you have a space in the variable name or in its value. You are not showing what you are doing. Why we have to guess? If it is in `txtname` then there are other 'forbidden' characters for url parameters and their values. You shoud url encode the whole string first.

Comment: @Tony: Any other option I have lots of variables like this.

Comment: Can you show the final URL that the app is sending to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to encode the `String` variable that you are ussing for name. This will prevent bad characters or replace spaces by *"+"* or *"%20"*

```
ru.execute(URLEncoder.encode(urlSuffix, "utf-8"));
```

Or better, use an *URI* builder

```
// This will get the final URL for request
String uri = Uri.parse(REGISTER_URL)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("name", txtname)
                .build().toString();
```

Comment: After put ru.execute(URLEncoder.encode(urlSuffix, "utf-8")); then get <html> message from server side

Comment: And what it says?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use the URLEncoder

   ```
   String urlSuffix= URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
   ```
2. Specify the method as GET

   ```
   String URL = "http://android.com/android_test/httpget.php? +name=urlSuffix"

    URL url=new URL(ur_url);
   urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
   ```